# Find the minimum value of $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n |x-a_i|$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization

Let $a_1 \lt a_2 \lt \dots \lt a_n$.

Find the minimum value of $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n |x-a_i|$.

My guess is the minimum occurs at the middle point. However, I don't know how to show this since I can't use calculus here. What kinds of idea should I use? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: What is $a_i$ here?

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1397867/12042) for the specific case $n=4$; it generalizes easily, though you do have to distinguish odd $n$ from even $n$.

Comment: Global min, I assume?

Comment: @MichaelDyrud I edited it! Kaster Yes!!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I get the idea intuitively that the function is decreasing as we move to the middle then increases as we move further away. But I don't know how to show it mathematically...

Comment: @takecare: Use the idea in that answer: pair up the points $a_k$, starting at the ends, and notice that as you move right away from $a_k$, you move towards $a_{n+1-k}$ by the same amount, so that $|x-a_k|+|x-a_{n+1-k}|$ remains constant.

Comment: One way to see it is to look at the value of $\vert x - a_j \vert$ on each interval $[a_i,a_{i +1}]$ in order to get rid of the absolute values.

Comment: Can you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Okay how is this answer?

Let $x$ be in any interval $[a_{j-1},a_j]$. Now let $y$ be in $[a_j,a_{j+1}]$, and $|x-a_j|=|y-a_j|$. Then $|y-a_i|=|x-a_i|+|y-x|$ if $i\le j-1$, and $|y-a_i|=|x-a_i|-|y-x|$ if $i\ge j-1$.

Hence, $f(y)=f(x)+|y-x|\{(j-1)+(n-j)\}=f(x)+|y-x|\{(2j-1)-n\}$.

Now it is clear that as $x$ moves to the middle $a_i$, $f$ decrease, then increases as it moves further away.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a_1<a_2<\dots<a_n$. Then on each interval $\;(a_k,a_{k+1})$,

$$ f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^k(a_i-x)+\sum_{i=k+1}^n(x-a_i)=(n-2k)x+\sum_{i=1}^ka_i-\sum_{i=k+1}^n a_i $$
Thus, $f(x)$ is decreasing on $\;(a_k,a_{k+1})$  as long as $n-2k>0$, i.e. $k<\dfrac n2$, increasing as soon as $k>\dfrac n2$.

We see there are two cases:

- If $n$ is odd; $n=2p+1$, there is a unique minimum, attained at the *middle point*  $a_{p+1}$, and its value is:
  $$f(a_{n+1})= -a_1-\dots-a_n+a_{n+2}+\dots+a_{2p+1}.$$
- If $n$ is even: $n=2p$, the function attains its minimum on the *middle interval* $\;[a_p,a_{p+1}]$ and its value is:
  $$-a_1-\dots-a_p+a_{p+1}+\dots+a_{2p}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is good, the answer is the median of $(a_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$.

Let $f_1(x)=\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\vert x-a_i\vert$. Then you have, for all $x$:

$$f(x)=\vert x-a_1\vert + f_1(x)+\vert x - a_n\vert$$

Considering this equation, you can show that $f_1$ et $f$ have the same minimum, noticing that:

- the minimum is not outside $[a_1,a_n]$
- $\forall x\in\lbrack a_1,a_n\rbrack$, $f(x)=f_1(x)+(a_n-a_1)$

Repeating this, you can "forget" extremal points at each step. At the end you only have one or two points left. Then you just have to consider the two cases: $n$ even and $n$ odd.

Answer (score 0):

> My guess is the minimum occurs at the middle point

The middle (median) interval.  There are two median points if $n$ is even and $f$ is constant and minimum on the interval between them.  If $n$ is odd the interval reduces to a point.

This was the starting point of Median Regression.  Wikipedia attributes the idea to Boskovic in the 1700's, which would make it one of the first examples of regression methods.